# How to get NSURLSession to return Content-Length(http header) from server. Objective-c, ios

Tags: ios, http, head

I have spend many hours trying the various ideas found in posts on this question with no success. **When I use curl I get the desired header**: Content-Length.

Here is my latest attempt(found somewhere on SO):

```
- (void) trythis {

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:myURL];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"HEAD";


    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *uploadTask
        = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request
                 completionHandler:^(NSURL *url,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error) {
                     NSLog(@"handler size: %lld", response.expectedContentLength);
                     NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
                     NSDictionary* headers = [httpResponse allHeaderFields];
                     NSArray *keys = [headers allKeys];
                     for( NSString *key in keys){
                         NSLog(@"key: %@ : %@", key, [headers valueForKey:key]);
                     }
                     NSLog(@"");

                 }];

    // 5
    [uploadTask resume];
}
```

It returns these headers:

> key: Vary : Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
>      key: Server : Apache/2.4.12
>      key: Connection : Keep-Alive
>      key: Last-Modified : Sat, 13 Jun 2015 23:03:46 GMT
>      key: Content-Type : audio/mpeg
>      key: Accept-Ranges : bytes
>      key: Date : Tue, 12 Apr 2016 17:59:21 GMT
>      key: Content-Encoding : gzip

Using curl (on macbook) I get:

> curl -I http://boulderhomegrown.com/fiddletunes/JerusalemRidge-100.mp3
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>      Date: Tue, 12 Apr 2016 14:55:17 GMT
>      Server: Apache/2.4.12
>      Last-Modified: Sat, 13 Jun 2015 23:03:46 GMT
>      ETag: "2ec0bc0-1a172e-5186e3ca6b55f"
>      Accept-Ranges: bytes
>      Content-Length: 1709870
>      Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
>      Content-Type: audio/mpeg

NOTE the Content-Length!! And, of course, the url is the same in both. It's an instance variable in my objective-c.

Comment: What was wrong with `response.expectedContentLength` as you used?

Comment: Looks like your curl command is doing a GET request and your NSURLSession a HEAD request. What happens if you remove `request.HTTPMethod = @"HEAD";` ?

Comment: EricS, the response does include the correct value for expectedContentLength. The NSURL* points to a local temp file; which is to be expected for a GET. It seems that this is downloading the file and reporting the number of bytes transferred. My object was to fetch the file so as to initialize the progress view. I don't want to download the file before getting the remote file size. And to be nit-picky, the Content-Length header is not included in the response. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Correction: My object was to fetch the file SIZE only so as to initialize the progress bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the request you are sending has header - Accept-Encoding : gzip, deflate and the server apache in this case don't add the header content-length(by default for larger files). So if you replace that header with value: identity. It will provide the correct size of the file.

Here is the code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:myURL];
request.HTTPMethod = @"HEAD";
[request addValue:@"identity" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
```

Just have to add the field and you will have the right header in the response like curl -I does.

Comment: Kaloyan, this does cause the response to contain the header Content-Length; thanks, A follow up question: the NSURL* in the completionHandler points to a tmp file on the device. Did the file get uploaded, do you think? I don't have a tool to view that directory to see.

Comment: @kaloyan how to get it with POST method. identity header is not working for me.